# gitlab Error 500 after updating when viewing projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, gitlab

`dpkg-query -W gitlab gitlab  7.3.2-omnibus-1`

We have gitlab 6.9.2 running on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. After following the instructions found here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/update.md

to update to 7.3.2, everything seemed fine however when trying to view a project we get error 500.

Everytime I try to access one of the pages I see this error when running 
`sudo gitlab-ctl tail postgresql`

```
ERROR:  relation "users_star_projects" does not exist at character 323
STATEMENT: SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
FROM pg_attribute a 
LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
WHERE a.attrelid = '"users_star_projects"'::regclass
AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Also I see this error listed in  `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log:`

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 42ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users_star_projects" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users_star_projects"'::r...
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"users_star_projects"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
):
  app/models/user.rb:522:in `starred?'
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:63:in `show'
```

If there a way I can fix or add the missing relation?

Comment: Sounds like you probably skipped a database schema upgrade step when you did the upgrade.

Comment: This sort of problem still happening when I upgrade from gitlab-ce 10.4 to 10.6

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I posted the issue on gitlab, which helped me fix the problem. 
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/277

In case anyone else has this issue or comes across this I am posting a quick run down on how I fixed it.
In my case I was missing some DB relations. So you can check that by running
`sudo gitlab-rake db:migrate:status` 
If any of those say down, then they were not applied.

You can try to fix that by running 
`sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
in my case that did not fix the problem. I had to manually tell it to run the DB migrations with the following command 
`sudo gitlab-rake db:migrate`

After that when I ran `sudo gitlab-rake db:migrate:status` they were all up and I have no more 500 errors when using the website.

Comment: Helped me alot i got the same problem!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still valid in 2021. I was going to re-install GitLab because of that issue I can not resolve

Answer (score 0):

I have upgrade from 11 to 14 under centos and this works for me

```
sudo gitlab-rake db:migrate:status
sudo gitlab-rake db:migrate
sudo gitlab-ctl stop
sudo gitlab-ctl start
```