# How to upgrade omnibus gitlab 7.2.1?

Tags: debian, gitlab

Im really confused because Gitlab is using different names of their product. So there exist "Gitlab", "Gitlab CE, "Gitlab CI", "Gitlab Omnibus" and "Gitlab paid"

I found some correct documentation as I think for my gitlab [version](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/update.md).

Via help page i found out that gitlab which im running at my server got the version `GitLab 7.2.1 ff1633f`

I failed at this step:

```
Install the latest package

# Ubuntu/Debian:
sudo dpkg -i gitlab_x.x.x-omnibus.xxx.deb

# CentOS:
sudo rpm -Uvh gitlab-x.x.x_xxx.rpm


root@debian:~# sudo dpkg -i gitlab_x.x.x-omnibus.xxx.deb
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von gitlab_x.x.x-omnibus.xxx.deb (--install):
 Auf das Archiv kann nicht zugegriffen werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 gitlab_x.x.x-omnibus.xxx.deb
root@debian:~#
```

What to do now? Im not an linux expert, just started with it.

Comment: Found the solution on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224649/gitlab-error-500-after-updating-when-viewing-projects/26268429#comment45072161_26268429

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that the file you want to install is not found. You have to download the file first and then exchange the x to the downloaded version. I would suggest you follow the steps described on https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/7-7-stable/doc/update.md for the update steps itself.

You can always find the latest stable omnibus version to download on https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/ but follow the  update document first

There are two major kinds: OpenSource/Community edition and the paid Enterprise Edition you have to subscribe to. The Enterprise version is based on the free version and comes with some additional features (compare them [here](https://about.gitlab.com/features/).

- Gitlab is generically used term for the git server. References the most times the CE version.
- Gitlab CE is the OpenSource Gitlab Server **C**ommunity **E**dition
- [Gitlab CI](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/) is basically an add-on for gitlab adding **C**ontinous **I**ntegration option to the basic Gitlab Server (gitlab CI seems to be part of the the Omnibus installer)
- "Gitlab paid": I have never heard this phrasing, I would assume it is "Gitlab EE"
- Gitlab EE (not reference by you) is the paid **E**nterprise **E**dition you have to subscribe to. It come with some additional non-free features.
- "Gitlab Omnibus" is a in my opinion unlucky chosen phrasing. It indicates that the Omnibus installer is used.

In the past installation was always manual requiring multiple steps. The current recommended way is the installation of Gitlab (EE as well as CE) with the Omnibus installer. It basically requires only 3 steps: install package, edit configuration file, tell gitlab to add this new configuration.