# Gitlab 500 Error after upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ldap, gitlab

I just upgraded my Gitlab Omnibus install from 7.3 to 7.9.1, and now rather than showing a login page, Gitlab just shows a 500 error page (see below)

I also noticed the following in /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-31 13:36:56 -0400
Processing by DashboardController#show as HTML
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "identities" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"identities"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"identities"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 135ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "identities" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"identities"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"identities"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
):
  app/models/user.rb:425:in `ldap_user?'
  app/models/user.rb:463:in `requires_ldap_check?'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:208:in `ldap_security_check'
```

I should note that we use LDAP authentication with Gitlab.

Comment: Managed to find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224649/gitlab-error-500-after-updating-when-viewing-projects?rq=1

Comment: Can you add this as your answer and accept it? It might get marked as a Dupe, but still a good question since I had the same problem.